# Include only Zend Framework 2.2.4 Mail lib

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-mail

On lot of old posts the answer was just to go

```
include('full path to zend lib/Some lib.php');
```

but in zend 2.2.4 in one module there is lot of dirs and subdirs I don't think it would be good to include all of that.

Also saw lot of answers:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

but because of above mentioned problem I can't use it either.

So question is how to upload just email module (like every regular class) and use it? 
Is it even possible or I have to install full framework (I had lot of troubles installing it and still didn't manage to install...) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you should be able to install any [Zend framework component](http://framework.zend.com/downloads/composer) via [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/).

```
"require": {
    "zendframework/zend-mail": "2.2.4"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but I am still a little confused. Do I need to create composer.json? In my project directory? And can you tell me how should full file look like?

Comment: If you have successfully downloaded Composer, you can execute the following command line: `php composer.phar require zendframework/zend-mail:2.2.4` while being inside your main directory. It will create the files needed.

Comment: For me it worked like this: composer require zendframework/zend-mail:2.2.4
Now I got 'vendor' folder with subdirectories 'composer' and 'zendframework' and file 'autoload.php'. All files are in there now but again I need to include them somehow? I tried include('vendor/autoload.php'); but it isn't working. Can you tell me how to include it now?

Comment: Including `vendor/autoload.php` should be enough. Describe "it isn't working" in more detail.

Comment: I have used include('vendor/autoload.php'); but I got this error : ' Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap' not found'

Comment: Oh, beg my pardon I was reading old documentation. However your answer is completely correct.